# Is there a way to make a link file which works with curl or wget to download images through docker hub private registry?

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu

I have 5-6 images saved on docker hub private registries. I have to make a script file for downloading all those images on say ubuntu os.
For that i have Dockerfile for all the images but the problem is how can i make them excutable through a click of public link. Any thoughts on that would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The easiest path would probably be to distribute a `docker-compose.yml` that references the various `image:` your combined application needs.  `docker-compose up` will automatically pull (download) the images if they're not already present locally.

Comment: @DavidMaze can we give build reference of repo on hub in docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: what should be the structure for docker-compose up to download the file from hub?